# My double-closure function is not working

Tags: swift, swift3, escaping, closures, completionhandler

I have two async function which send requests to my server.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    weak var weakself = self
    self.unregisterPushServer(token: token!) { [weak self] success in
        print("0")
        if success {
           print("1")
           weakself?.unregisterPushInfoKeychain(token: token!)
           print("2")
           if let this = self {
               print("PLEASE")
               weakself?.registerPushServer(token: token!) { [weak this] success in
                   print("3")
                   if success {
                       print("4")
                       this?.registerPushInfoKeychain()
                       print("5")
                   }
               }
           }
           print("success")
        }
    }
}
```

And the functions are

```
private func registerPushServer(token: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    request() { (data, error) in 
        if data != nil {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }

private func unregisterPushServer(token: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    request2() { (data, error) in 
        if data != nil {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
```

But in console,

```
0
1
2
success
```

not seemed to executes codes after my PLEASE sign.

Why is my code is not working?

I first thought that the problem was about the queue, but it was not.

Comment: Have you actually checked whether the condition `if let this = self` is actually true? Moreover, all those weak self statements seem to be unnecessary, as far as I can tell from the context, none of your closures capture self.

Comment: I have tried to remove that condition and revised like this [this](https://pastebin.com/j5Vng1DZ). It seemed to print 0 1 2 PLEASE success but still not showing after 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was not in this code.

When I call this function, I did it like this.

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    let pushService = PushService()
    pushService.updateRegistrationStatus(token: fcmToken)
}
```

the

```
pushService.updateRegistrationStatus(token: fcmToken)
```

was the function which contains the code I asked above.

In this situation, the function **updateRegistrationStatus** is not guaranteed because pushService itself is released by ARC when **messaging(...)** function block is end.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let pushService = PushService()

    ...

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        self.pushService.updateRegistrationStatus(token: fcmToken)
    }
}
```

Now the pushService object is not released because it is declared as a global variable.

Comment: That's not a global variable, only a class instance property.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line:

```
weak var weakself = self
```

By including `[weak self]` in the closure's capture list, `self` automatically becomes weak.

Try and replace the instances of `weakself` with just `self`.

I'm also thinking you may not even need the `if let this = self` condition.

I hope this helps.

Comment: [Revised Code](https://pastebin.com/j5Vng1DZ) this is not working either. It prints 0 1 2 PLEASE success.. still not showing after 3.